# Creating three responsive, vertically stacked, and vertically scrollable divs with content using Flex

Tags: html, css, flexbox, frontend

I've been trying to do this for to no avail. I can get the three divs stacked and scrollable, but when I resize the viewport vertically, it seems like the divs aren't taking up the right space as the bottom one ends up getting cut off at some point.

I want something like this:

```
__________
|Scroll  |
|________|
|Scroll  |   
|________|
|Scroll  |
|________|
```

Where each of the scroll divs are inside of a flex box with `flex-direction: column`, each have `flex-grow: 1` (so they each take up the same vertical space). Any idea of how to do this?

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/7hrau1qo/22/

Comment: Hi. Welcome to Stack Overflow. Where's the code?

Comment: depends on what the inner content is.

Comment: Oops, i'll add a jsfiddle to the post.

Comment: @ImmortalDude Currently in the fiddle i'm trying with just text, but in implementation there are more complex components.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/vkmubj29/, is this something you want?

Comment: @ImmortalDude yes! I think this gave me an idea of whats going wrong, I think I have padding or something in a higher component thats causing it to be cut off since the divs are styled with 'vh' units. Thanks, i'll see if this works

Comment: glad you found the problem, good luck fixing